# When behaviour-testing Angular Components is it possible to lookup the instance of another Component?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, bdd

I am testing an Angular toolbar component which triggers state-changing actions via `@ngrx/store`.

I have another component that is subscribed to those state changes in order to update its own internal state.

So in a `karma/jasmine` unit test, I trigger the click of a toolbar button. I simply then want to `spy` on the other component and assert it's change function was called.

So the question is, without changing the the existing components with `ViewParent/ViewChild` directives just for the tests which ofc would be considered a code-smell, *how do I lookup the instance of an Angular Component*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the correct instance of a child component in order test behaviours like this.

You can query the parent to find a child by directive:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
let childComponentInstance: ChildComponent;

// After setting up your component in the TestBed...
parentComponentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
...

// Reference the child component from your parent component fixture
childComponentInstance = parentComponentFixture
    .debugElement
    .query(By.directive(ChildComponent))
    .componentInstance;
```

You can then use `childComponentInstance` in your test methods.

As you mentioned, this is no longer really a unit test and more of a behaviour test.

(It may be necessary to call `detectChanges()` on the `parentComponentFixture` to properly load the child depending on what is being bound to it)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be overthinking things.

@ngrx/store allows you to subscribe to this generic store that exists outside of any component tree. So, if you want to send events into your @ngrx/store and subscribe to to that @ngrx/store in some other component, then when testing that other component, simply create your store, send your events and see if your component under test responds to those 'store events' properly.

And when you're testing the first component that's sending your events, then spy on the store and confirm that it's receiving the proper events from your first component.

If your tests confirm that the first component is sending the events properly and you can confirm that the second component responds to the events properly, then you have properly unit tested both sides of your component interactions through the store.

Comment: I sort of agree with you from a unit-test perspective and i did specify that in the post.  But then it is not really describing the behaviour in an encapsulated way. Someone could delete the first component's call to action and unit-test and the second component's test would still pass - yet the behaviour is broken. I guess this highlights the gap between TDD and BDD. I want to test the behaviour without necessarily doing a full e2e test.

Comment: well, to me, unit testing is about testing 'units'. So, if you want to test the whole interaction, then it's either about looking for a bigger 'unit' that encapsulates both sides of that interaction, even though such a unit test will more resemble an integration test. The good news is that you can use the same sort of test setup for those types of integration tests - you don't necessarily have to switch to protractor tests